# microsoft edge mjpeg support

Tags: mjpeg, microsoft-edge

Microsoft state that the Edge browser has native support for MJPEG multi-part streams. (https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status//)

The following HTML renders a MJPEG stream in all web-kit browsers (Chrome, Safari iOS & OSX, Firefox), but it won't render in Edge.

```html
<INPUT TYPE=image NAME="MJPEGStream" SRC="http://192.168.1.190/webfiles/CameraPlayback.cgi" WIDTH="640" HEIGHT="480" BORDER=0>
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have same issue. Also event "load" or "error" doesn't trigger.

Comment: I also have the same issue have there been any progress yet?

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but MJPEGs are working without a problem for me in Edge - http://jsbin.com/vopenid

```
<img src="http://194.248.190.92/mjpg/video.mjpg" width="715" height="576" style="z-index:100;width:715px;height:576px"></body>
```

Since Your IP is a local one, I don't have a way to check if it is now working for you, however the same link I just provided works in the version of Edge that was shipping when you posted it.